# How to insert data of type java.util.Set into my sql database with column of type set using ibatis?

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis, ibatis

How to insert data of type java.util.Set into mysql db column of type set(mysql set type) ?

My POJO :

```
public class UserTEO 
{
    private Integer id;
    private Set changedfieldset;
    //getters and setters
}
```

xml file :

```
<sqlMap namespace="user"> 

    <typeAlias alias="USER" type="com.howtodoinjava.ibatis.demo.dto.UserTEO" />
    <insert id="addUser" parameterClass="USER">
        INSERT INTO USERINFO (ID,CHANGEDFIELDSET)
         VALUES(#id#,#changedfieldset#);
    </insert>
</sqlMap>
```

database :

```
CREATE TABLE USERINFO
(
    ID INT,
    CHANGEDFIELDSET SET('')
);
```

Exception :

```
com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in user.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the user.addUser-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the parameter mapping for the 'changedfieldset' property.
```

Please help. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you explicitly want to work with (old) ibatis and not Mybatis.
So here is the [documentation](https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/pdf/iBATIS-SqlMaps-2_en.pdf) I referenced to.

The Mysql SET expects a string of set values separated by commas and without white spaces: `StringUtils.join(set, ",")`. So you have to use a type handler to transform the java Set into this string: Extend [BaseTypeHandler](https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/dev/com/ibatis/sqlmap/engine/type/class-use/BaseTypeHandler.html), speceially overriding  `setParameter` method.

Then call as follows:

```
INSERT INTO USERINFO (ID,CHANGEDFIELDSET)
         VALUES(#id#,#changedfieldset,handler=YourCustomTypeHandlerTypeAlias#)
```

Comment: superb ! Thanks ! 
Meanwhile I changed the getter of my Set to return String which was working fine. But this is the genuine solution. Thanks Buddy .